# Command with argument within a command within a command

Tags: bash

Yes, that title is a complete mess. I didn't really know how else to describe it.

I'm setting up my RPi to run Homebridge in a screen on startup. I've edited my `rc.local` file to include this line:

`su - pi -c "screen -dm -S hbscreen homebridge"`

It creates a screen called "hbscreen" which executes the command "homebridge". Now the problem is that I'd like to add an argument so the command reads "homebridge -I".

Seeing as I like to just try things I simply added `-I` to the line and got this:

`su - pi -c "screen -dm -S hbscreen homebridge -I"`

But suddenly my RPi wouldn't boot anymore. So, I guess that wasn't the right way to go about it.

I've been googling for half an hour now and I can't seem to figure it out. What would be the correct notation? I'm guessing I need to let it know "homebridge -I" is one piece, but I'm assuming I can't use quotation marks within quotation marks like this:

`su - pi -c "screen -dm -S hbscreen "homebridge -I""`

Comment: What if you use single quotes instead of the inner double quotes? Also, you can escape the double quotes as `\"`.

Comment: @UltraInstinct Just tried escaping the double quotes, didn't work sadly. I restarted my Pi and the screen didn't even start up.

Comment: Forgot to add that I also tried the single quotes, same result. RPi would boot but no screen would have been started. Removing the quotes and `-I` makes everything run fine, but I need the `-I` for additional features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to someone on Reddit I managed to fix it by not putting everything in `rc.local` but instead making an .sh file in my home directory called `hbboot.sh` and running that instead.

rc.local:

```
su - pi -c "screen -dm -S hbscreen ~/hbboot.sh"
```

hbboot.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
homebridge -I "$@"
```